# Prove the application $\Phi$ is bijective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, applications

I am working on a problem set and I need some assistance with an exercise.

The exercise goes as follows:

> Let $A$ be a ring and $I \unlhd A$ an ideal. Given the natural projection $\pi : A \rightarrow A/I$ , $a\mapsto a+I$, prove that the application $\Phi : \{ideals \ of \ A/I \} \rightarrow \{ideals \ of \ A \ that \ contain \ I\}$, $J \mapsto \pi^{-1}(J)$, is bijective. The inverse of $\Phi$ is $K \mapsto \pi(K)$.

---

My solution:

I will start by proving that $\Phi$ is injective.

Given $a+I, b+I \in J$, I assume that  $\Phi(a+I)=\Phi(b+I)$, since $\Phi$ is given by $J\mapsto \pi^{-1}(J)$, we have $\Phi(a+I) = \pi^{-1}(a+I) = a$ and  $\Phi(b+I) = \pi^{-1}(b+I) = b$. Therefore $a = b$, and $\Phi$ is injective.

I continue by proving that $\Phi$ is surjective, but I get stuck. And to be honest, I think that my proof of injection is incorrect.

Any advice?

Kind regards.

---

Ps. I realized that this has to do with one of the Isomorphism theorems.

Comment: Well, definitely $\;a\in\pi^{-1}(a+I)\;$ , but that inverse image of that element in the quotient ring could have lots of elements more...As shown in your question. prove that $\;\Phi\;$ has an inverse...and that's all! This is the Correspondence Theorem for Rings.